# Enable tooltip and set markers in line charts using google charts

Tags: jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have created a graph using Google charts. I have attached the fiddle of the same.

I want the tooltip format to be something like `(r1=12% ,r2=5%)...` and not as shown in the graph. Also I want markers of 2 different colors at the starting and end point. Is it possible with google charts? I tried a lot but couldn't do it somehow. Can anyone help?

```
<div id="chart"></div>
```

```js
function test() {
    for (i = 0; i <= 90; i++) {
        var r1;
        var r2;

        r1 = i * 0.1 + (10 - i) * 0.05;
        r2 = (10 - i) * (10 - i) * 0.15 * 0.15;
        a.push([Math.sqrt(r2), r1]);
    }
}
var a = [["r1", "r2"]];

function drawChart() {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(a);
    var options = {
        isStacked: true,
        hAxis: {
            ticks: [0, 5, 10, 15, 20],
            gridlines: {
                color: 'none'
            },
            title: 'x',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'transparent'
            },
        },
        vAxis: {
            ticks: [0, 3, 6, 9, 12],
            title: 'y',
            gridlines: {
                color: 'gray',
                dataOpacity: 0.03
            },
        },
        colors: ['green'],
        legend: {
            position: 'none'
        },
        width: 380,
        height: 270,
        tooltip: {
            isHtml: false
        }
    };
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
google.charts.load('current', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

test();
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tes6nze9/

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/w77kysvk/1/

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please always place your code in the question so that it can be seen by visitors even if jsFiddle goes down. I've edited in for you this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure I follow *exactly*, but...

you can use [Column Roles](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available) to customize the Tooltip and Style of each point

see following example...

```js
var a = [[
  "r1",
  "r2",
  {role: 'tooltip', type: 'string'},
  {role: 'style', type: 'string'}
]];

function test(){
  for (i = 0;  i<= 90; i++) {
    var r1;
    var r2;
    var tooltip;
    var style;

    r1 = i* 0.1 + (10 - i) *0.05;
    r2 =  (10- i) * (10 - i) *0.15 *0.15;

    tooltip = 'r1='  + r1.toFixed(1) + '%' + '\nr2='  + r2.toFixed(1) + '%';

    if (i <= 0) {
      style = 'color: cyan; stroke-width: 5;';
    } else if (i >= 90) {
      style = 'color: magenta; stroke-width: 5;';
    } else {
      style = 'color: green;';
    }

    a.push([
      Math.sqrt(r2),
      r1,
      tooltip,
      style
    ]);
  }
}

google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {
    test();
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(a), {
      isStacked: true,
      hAxis: {
        ticks: [0,5,10,15,20],
        gridlines: {
          color: 'none'
        },
        title: 'x',
        gridlines: {
          color: 'transparent'
        },
      },
      vAxis: {
        ticks: [0,3,6,9,12],
        title: 'y',
        gridlines: {
          color: 'gray',
          dataOpacity: 0.03
        },
      },
      legend: {position: 'none'},
      width: 380,
      height: 270,
      tooltip: {isHtml: false},
      pointSize: 1
    });
  },
  packages:['corechart']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: yes it did.but i want the marker(CIRCLE) to appear when the graph is plot.and not on the hover.Is it possible?

Comment: it worked but the issue i came across is that i call my test() function and drawchart() function in the slider function .I have created the slider using jquery ui which works fine. The problem is that when i slide my slider and change its value ,my graph should also change.Rather than this a new graph is being plot for every change in slider value .and the previous graph remains as it is.So i am getting multiple graphs though i require only 1